# Centering div of varying dimensions

Tags: jquery

so i'm trying to always centre (both horizontally and vertically) my div of varying dimensions. I'm using jQuery, but it only centers my div when I resize the window. How can i get it to always center the div, without me having to resize the window first before it centres?

Thank you in advance: JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DZwPD/

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).resize(function(){

    $('.className').css({
        position:'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
    });

});

// To initially run the function:
$(window).resize();
```

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle. We need to see your markup.

Comment: @justtal see js fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is all u need

```
function centerDiv(){
$('#divResult').css({
    position:'absolute',
    left: $(window).width()/2,
    top: $(window).height()/2
});
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        centerDiv();
    });
});
```

hier ist demo [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qzAF/)

Comment: hi, it doesn't seem to be working. i think it's because mine is a div of varying width, and yours is just text. I'm not too sure.

Comment: u need wait until <video> loadded. add this for your script
document.getElementById("divResult").onloadedmetadata=centerDiv();

Answer (score 2):

Try like this -

```
function rePosition(){
    $('.className').css({
        position:'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('.className').outerWidth())/2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('.className').outerHeight())/2
    });
}
$(function(){
  $(window).resize(rePosition);
  rePosition();
});
```

Comment: i tried it, didn't seem to work. see my jsFiddle for my markup. thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Please try using,

```
 margin:0px auto;
```

in css

Comment: this will only center it horizontally but not vertically